# I'm having trouble building dockers

Tags: docker

I ran normally from the docker hub to running the image.

But I'm having trouble executing 'build' command.
There appears to be a path problem, but any path given in the current working directory cannot be resolved. Can you give me any advice here?

(I am in wsl2 -  ubuntu 20.04)

[image: ubuntu 20.04 - zsh]

Comment: docker build -f <dockerFile> -t <tag> <contextFolder>

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  What actual command are you running, and what's the error message you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass the file name to build command, if the file name is `Dockerfile` just pass the context. use this instead:

`docker build -t python-test .`